# Make an event that Catch the Selected RadioButton - Using C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, radio-button

I have listed a series of questions and each number can be two possible answers, only one of them is that you can select, for such the reason I grouped in a GroupBox and two RadioButton put each GroupBox. The problem is that if they select an option that I want you must add an extra comment for this response, only when you select that specific response. However, there are 25 questions and make each event RadioButton increase for each lot code and not be optimized, there will be some form of that once the change is made response in each GroupBox is generalize so take that GroupBox I was there and verify what that change, ie: answer 1 or answer 2. And the name of GroupBox can work it more practical. Can you? Create an event that is waiting to cambiod and each RadioButton and it takes the response data. Thank you! -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one handler to handle the same event from multiple radio buttons, then inside the handler look at the `sender` to determine which box was selected.

In circumstances like this, I'll use the `tag` property of the control to store some information about where I want the data to go back to.  In your group box problem, I'd store the tag on the group box:

```
this.radioButton1.Click += this.radioButtonx_Click;
this.radioButton2.Click += this.radioButtonx_Click;
this.radioButton3.Click += this.radioButtonx_Click;
this.radioButton4.Click += this.radioButtonx_Click;

private void radioButtonx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (((sender as RadioButton).Parent as GroupBox).Tag as MyWidget).MyProperty 
        = (sender as RadioButton).Text
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will tray this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to make use of ajax and use a div which the comment can be inserted along with the selected radio button and then stored.

Alternatively you can use one method in the bank end to capture that information. You would still have to call it for each individual radio button though.

If this is not what you are attempting to do please clarify.

Comment: Thanks, I forget to tell you that is Windows Form